# Laravel - валидация при multiple input file

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется PHP код:

```
public function upload()
{
    validator()->make(request()->all(), [
        'images' => 'required|file|mimes:txt,docx'
    ])->validate();
    foreach(request()->images as $image) {
        $image->store('images');
    }
}
```

И HTML код:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('upload.images') }}" class="panel-body" id="upload-images-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="file" name="images[]" title="Загрузить изображение" class="btn btn-default" id="upload-images" multiple>
</form>
```

Если убрать код валидации, то файлы загружаются, но как провести валидацию при мультизагрузке?

Answer (score 0):

В Laravel выше 5.2 можно сделать так:

```
validator()->make(request()->all(), [
   'images.*' => 'required|file|mimes:txt,docx'
])->validate();
```

Comment: Подскажите плиз, а как сделать валидацию на загрузку определенного количества файлов?

Comment: @АндрейИноземцев, вопросы стоит задавать отдельными вопросами.

Comment: @АндрейИноземцев добавьте правило в массив, `'images' => 'max:10',` будет ограничение в 10 файлов

Answer (score 0):

Вот так :

```
protected function put(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [
        'images'   => 'array',
        'images.*' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:20000',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $validator->errors()->all();
    }
}
```